# Understanding the Homotopy Invariance of Fiber Bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

I'm trying to understand the proof of Theorem 2.1 in "The Topology of Fiber Bundles" found online at [http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/fiber.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eralph/fiber.pdf). [image]

[image]

What I don't understand is how do we actually define $\tilde{H}$ and the claim that "This is clearly a bundle isomorphism since it induces the identity map on both the base space and on the fibers".

I'm not sure what does "induces the identity on fibers" means? hence I don't know how to check that $\tilde{H}$ map does induces the identity on fibers. And I don't know why such condition actually implies isomorphism.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the bundles $f_0^*(E)\to X$ and $H^*(E)\to X \times I$. By the theorem which is mentioned you get the bundle map 
$$\begin{array}{c}f_0^*(E) \times I &\to &E\\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
B\times I &\to & B\end{array}
$$

By the universal property of a pullback, the given maps give us a bundle map to $H^*(E)$:
$$\begin{array}{c}f_0^*(E) \times I &\to &H^*E\\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
B\times I &\stackrel {id} \to & B \times I\end{array}
$$

But by restricting you get that this is a bundle isomorphism. But by restricting to $B\times 1$ you also get a bundle isomorphism $f_0^*E \to f_1^*E$.

Let me know if you would like to have further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only point in the proof that I don't understand is why is the map $f^*_0(E) \times I \rightarrow H^*E$ an isomorphism. If you could expand the reasoning that would be great.

Comment: Because $f_0^*E\times I\to E$ is fibrewise an isomorphism, since $f_0^*E \to E$ is one, as well as $H^*E \to E$ is fibrewise an isomorphism. Hence $f_0^*E \times I \to H^*E \to E$ is fibrewise an iso, the latter map in the composition is fibrewise an iso, hence also the former. So you are left to show that $id$ is an isomorphism of topological spaces. Is it alright now?